# How to move C:\User\UserName\.Android folder

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to create a portable configuration for Eclipse on a thumb drive. The only setting I can't find is Android wants to use C:\User\UserName.Adroid folder.

I can't find a way to change it to point to a different folder.

I added ANDROID_SDK_HOME to the environment variable but Eclipse still wants to point to C:\User\UserName.Adroid.

Anyone have any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: what you mean that's eclipse can't find `android sdk`

Comment: I figured it out. I had to restart the computer and it worked. I must have been a background process running.

Answer (score 0):

It started working after I restarted the computer.